# Quartz.net issue in Asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, quartz-scheduler

I am using Quartz.NET scheduler in my MVC Application

like

```
public class JobScheduler
 {
    public static void Start()
    {
        IScheduler scheduler = StdSchedulerFactory.GetDefaultScheduler();
        scheduler.Start();

        IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create<AccountUnlockJob>().Build();

        ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
            .WithDailyTimeIntervalSchedule
              (s =>
                 s.WithIntervalInMinutes(1)
                .OnEveryDay()
                .StartingDailyAt(TimeOfDay.HourAndMinuteOfDay(0, 0))
              )
            .Build();

        scheduler.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);
    }
}
```

and in Another class

```
public class AccountUnlockJob : IJob
{
    public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        Getusers();
    }
    public void Getusers()
    {
        ResLandEntities reslandEntities = new ResLandEntities();
        var accountLockedUsers = reslandEntities.RL_USERS.Where(m => m.ACCT_LOCKED == true).ToList();
        foreach (var user in accountLockedUsers)
        {
            int currentHour = DateTime.Now.Hour;
            int userLockedTime = DateTime.Parse(user.DT_MOD.ToString()).Hour;


            var lockedUser=reslandEntities.RL_USERS.SingleOrDefault(m=>m.ID.Equals(user.ID));
            lockedUser.ACCT_LOCKED=false;
            lockedUser.DT_MOD=DateTime.Now;
            lockedUser.MOD_BY="safdf";
            reslandEntities.SaveChanges(); // Getting like No Source Code Available

        }
    }

}
```

Everything fine, But when I want to update my data into database using LINQ, getting like

```
 "No Source Available"
  Locating source for 'c:\Work\OpenSource\quartznet\src\Quartz\Core\JobRunShell.cs'. (No checksum.)
  The file 'c:\Work\OpenSource\quartznet\src\Quartz\Core\JobRunShell.cs' does not exist.
```

What does it mean, is it I can't update the database in scheduler code? Please help me anyone?

Comment: Seems like you have to download the Quartz source code and reference it to be able to get the specific error or you could try enabling its logging option.

Comment: Can you give some reference links.. to use it?

Comment: I would advise AGAINST using Quartz.net in ASP.Net. The default settings of IIS8 (in previous versions there isn't even an option to disable this) would kill long running processes like schedulers. Quartz won't be running for very long...

Comment: Well, you can find the source code at https://github.com/quartznet/quartznet and this post could help you to configure logging http://geekswithblogs.net/TarunArora/archive/2012/11/17/quartz.net-windows-service-configure-logging.aspx

Comment: Is it we should add in a Windows Service? or we can add in MVC Application

Comment: +1 to Aron, just queue up jobs in ASP.NET (you could have a DB backed queue), have a scheduled run (could be windows service) to actually process the jobs. And on your particular issue, use [Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/quartz/) to get reference to Quartz